# Running processes simultaneously, Bash

Tags: bash, process

I would like to run `n` processes (in my case simulations) simultaneously, using bash.
Right now this is what I'm running:

```
for file in $ini/SAN*.ini;
do
    echo "Running $file...";
    temp=$(basename $file .ini)
    mosrun -G opp_run -r 0 -u Cmdenv -n ..:../../src -l ../../src/inet SAN.ini > $outputs/$temp.out;
done
```

Problem is, the loop only progresses to the next iteration after the simulation is done. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run your command in the background by adding a `&` after it.

Should make them run in parallell, although in the background.

(Small side note: the processes will continue to run even if you abort the script, so you might want to add a `trap` to kill the processes if you hit for eg. ctrl-c when script is running. Look at bash manual.)